# Como fazer traduções automáticas?

Tags: html, css, json

Eu tenho uma página **HTML**e gostaria de te-la em varias *línguas*
Porém **não** queria fazer uma página para cada *língua* e sair editando no HTML.

*Existe* alguma maneira de eu fazer um **documento externo**, um JSON, *não sei*, onde eu coloco somente as **traduções** e os textos **são atualizados automaticamente** caso o *usuário* deseje?

Utilizo bootstrap e angular no meu site.

Comment: Em C# uso  `Resources`. Em query, tem alguns [plugins](https://www.sitepoint.com/10-jquery-translator-plugins/), não sei ao certo mas creio que a tradução deles não são muito boas, estilo o Google.

Comment: Mas o que desejo fazer é eu mesmo escrever as traduções.

Comment: Qual a linguagem server-side que usa?

Comment: Em Angular devem existir inúmeras soluções para o seu problema. [Uma, por exemplo](https://angular-translate.github.io/docs/#/guide/07_multi-language).

Comment: @JuniorVilasBoas com a sugestão do Marconi, você mesmo escreve as traduções.

Answer (score 2):

Para angular, existe um plugin chamado [angular-translate](https://github.com/angular-translate/angular-translate) que é excelente e é muito rápido para o que ele pretende fazer.

Mas existem modos fáceis sim, além destes plugins, existe uma especificação chamada i18n que visa padronizar essa parte de traduções. Você pode encontrar um pouco disso [aqui](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/i18n) e também existe um outro projeto mantido pela Mozilla, que é basicamente um framework chamado [l20n](http://l20n.org/) que mantém a localização na mão dos localizadores e tradutores, ele pode ser usado em qualquer tipo de projeto.

A atualização automática e a alternância entre os arquivos pode ser feita por estes frameworks, mas você ainda vai precisa traduzir o seu site em partes. Também é possível utilizar o google tradutor para gerar uma tradução instantânea, o trabalho é mínimo, mas o resultado não é tão bom também...